# Changes in LogCat from Android 4.0.4 to Android 4.1

Tags: android, logcat

I've just tried Android Jelly Bean, and I noticed that the `LogCat` has changed appearance in `Eclipse`. Usualy a

```
try {
  ..
} catch(Exception e) {
   Log.e("Tag here", e.getMessage());
}
```

Will be marked with the color red, and a

```
int i = 5;
int j = 5;
int k = i * j; 

Log.i("Sum is: ", Integer.toString(k));
```

will be marked with the color green.

When I develop applications for Android 4.1 in Eclipse the LogCat will just show a questionmark under the section

1. Level
2. Time
3. PID
4. Tag

And everything outputted to `LogCat` will be marked as a Waring(W), no matter what I'm logging out. And everything will have to color orange. This is pretty annoying when I try to locate what I outputted to `LogCat`.

Does anybody "suffer" from the same problem? Is there any fixes to this, if so how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: u should update your ADT plug-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update Android SDK tools and the Android-Eclipse plugin to the latest versions and the problems will go away.